# The server could not complete your request : Opening a site in SharePoint 2013 designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, iis, anonymous-authentication

I work in SharePoint Designer 2013. I want to open my site I received the following error.

[image]

Then I clicked "Details". But details are empty.

[image]

I researched same issue on the net and I found this solve. They said "Enabling Anonymous Authentication for your SharePoint Web Application & SharePoint Web Services in IIS Manager will resolve the issue. "  I tried this solve. But my issue didn't solve. What else should I do? I can't open my sites. Please help me.

Comment: Are you able to browse the site?

Answer (score 0):

Try to recycle the app pool/reset IIS after you have made that setting. [Here](http://akavitgroup.com/blog/sharepoint/sharepoint-designer-2013-server-could-not-complete-your-request-error-and-fix) is another possible solution. The last time I had observed this issue was when the RAM on my dev server was filled up to the brim and the server was consuming a lot of CPU. I would suggest to try and stop unwanted heavy services and processes and check if you can open the site.